# Organizing data by Name and ID in Google Sheets: Sorting and Copying Columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula

Dear stackoverflow members,

I am currently working on a project where I need to copy particular column data from a source sheet to a destination sheet and sort them Name and ID wise. The data starts from A2 in the source sheet and flows to A3 in the destination sheet.

I have tried using a script to fetch the data from the source sheet, but I am looking to sort the data in a particular way, as shown in the attached reference table. Additionally, I am wondering if it's possible to have a checklist inside the dropdown, as shown in the attached GIF.

Brief: I am trying to extract specific data from a sheet that contains date-wise information and populate it in another sheet by filtering it based on dates between a "from" and "to" date.

I have attempted to use the "Query and Filter" formulas, but I am having difficulty grouping the data by name and displaying it under specific headings within the filter sheet. I have attached a picture for your reference.

Would you please be able to provide me with some guidance on how to group the data by name and display it under specific headings within the filter sheet? Additionally, would you recommend adding a blank row or separator at the end of each set of data to help split the view for identification?

I tried below formula & Script for getting data from another sheet but I could not achieve Name wise, Blank Row at bottom each set. and Total hrs for Name as shown in the sample image

Formula below:

`=QUERY(Log!B:S, "select J,L,O,P,S where B = "&A2&" and J >= date '"&TEXT(L2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and J <= date '"&TEXT(V2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",0)

=Filter({Log!J:J,Log!L:L,Log!T:T,Log!AB:AB,Log!P:P,Log!X:X,Log!AF:AF,Log!O:O,Log!S:S},Log!B:B=A1,Log!J:J>=L1,Log!J:J<=V1)`

Script below

```
function groupingdata() {
var groupwiseSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("groupwise");
var logSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Log");
var empCode = groupwiseSheet.getRange("A1").getValue();
var nameRange = groupwiseSheet.getRange("B1:E1");
var fromDateRange = groupwiseSheet.getRange("L1");
var toDateRange = groupwiseSheet.getRange("V1");


// Get the merged value for the name range
var name = nameRange.getMergedRanges()[0].getValue();

// Get the value for the from date range and convert to Date object
var fromDate = new Date(fromDateRange.getValue());

// Get the value for the to date range and convert to Date object
var toDate = new Date(toDateRange.getValue());

var logData = logSheet.getRange("A1:BM").getValues();
var groupwiseData = [];

for (var i = 1; i < logData.length; i++) {
    if (logData[i][1] >= fromDate && logData[i][1] <= toDate && logData[i][2] == empCode && logData[i][3] == name) {

    groupwiseData.push([
    logData[i][0], // A to A (LogID)
    logData[i][1], // B to B (DATE)
    '=IMAGE("' + logData[i][5] + '", 4, 100, 100)', // C
    '=IMAGE("' + logData[i][13] + '", 4, 100, 100)', // D
      null, // E (skip)
      null, // F (skip)
    logData[i][6],  // G to G  / 1st ClockIn 
    logData[i][7],  // H to H / 1st In Location / H to H
    logData[i][8],  // I to I / 1-Activity to I
    logData[i][10], // K to J / 1-Project  K to J
    logData[i][12], // M to K  / 1-Note
    logData[i][22], // W to L / 2-IN-TIME
    logData[i][23], // X to M / 2-IN-Loc
    logData[i][24], // Y to N /2-Activity
    logData[i][26], // AA to O  / 2-Project
    logData[i][28], // AC to P  / 2-Note  
    logData[i][37], // AL to Q  / 3-IN-TIME   
    logData[i][39], // AN to R  /3-IN-Loc
    logData[i][40], // AO to S /3-Activity
    logData[i][42], // AQ to T /3-Project
    logData[i][44], // AS to U /3-Note
    logData[i][14], // O to V /1-OUT-TIME 
    logData[i][15], // P to W /1-OUT-Loc
    logData[i][16], // Q to X /1-OUT-Activity
    logData[i][20], // U to Y /1-OUT-Note
    logData[i][30], // AE to Z /2-OUT-TIME
    logData[i][31], // AF to AA /2-OUT-Loc
    logData[i][32], // AG to AB /2-OUT-Activity
    logData[i][36], // AK to AC /2-OUT-Note
    logData[i][46], // AU to AD /3-OUT-TIME
    logData[i][47], // AV to AE /3-OUT-Loc
    logData[i][48], // AW to AF /3-OUT-Activity
    logData[i][52], // BA to AG /3-OUT-Note
     
   
    //logData[i][55], // BC to AH + Symbol  
    //logData[i][56], // BD to AI Formula Add Hrs
    //logData[i][57], // BE to AJ Formula SiteMark
    //logData[i][58], // BF to AK Empty empty
    //logData[i][59], // BG to AL Formula Recorded Hrs
    //logData[i][60], // BH to AM Formula Auto LunchHr Adjust
    //logData[i][61], // BI to AN Formula Manual Hrs Adjust        

  ]);
}

  }}
```

But I was expecting like Name wise shorting

**Expected Results > Name Wise**

| ID | DATE | Day | Total HRS | Total Pay |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **120** | **MAR 1 to 30** | **Name1** | 20:00 | 2,500 |
| 5 | 06/03/2023 | Mon | 8:00 | 1,000 |
| 518 | 07/03/2023 | Tue | 8:00 | 1,000 |
| 636 | 31/03/2023 | Fri | 4:00 | 500 |
| Blank space / Separator |  |  |  |  |
| **121** | **MAR 1 to 30** | **Name2** | 20:00 | 2,500 |
| 6 | 06/03/2023 | Mon | 8:00 | 1,000 |
| 519 | 07/03/2023 | Tue | 8:00 | 1,000 |
| 637 | 30/03/2023 | Thu | 4:00 | 500 |
| 638 | 31/03/2023 | Fri | 4:00 | 500 |
| Blank space / Separator |  |  |  |  |
| **122** | **MAR 1 to 30** | **Name3** | 20:00 | 2,500 |
| 7 | 06/03/2023 | Mon | 8:00 | 1,000 |
| 519 | 07/03/2023 | Tue | 8:00 | 1,000 |
| 637 | 30/03/2023 | Thu | 4:00 | 500 |
| Blank space / Separator |  |  |  |  |

**Table showing how the data is stored initially in another sheet (Log sheet)**

| LOGID | DATE | EMP CODE | EMLOYEE NAME | Total Hours | Total Pay |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 06/03/2023 | 121 | Name2 |  |  |
| 425 | 31/03/2023 | 101 | Name12 |  |  |
| 468 | 31/03/2023 | 157 | Name5 |  |  |
| 469 | 31/03/2023 | 120 | Name1 |  |  |
| 470 | 31/03/2023 | 151 | Name4 |  |  |
| 515 | 01/04/2023 | 120 | Name1 |  |  |
| 516 | 01/04/2023 | 169 | Name7 |  |  |

[image]
[image][image]

Comment: Could you share an image/table showing how the data is stored initially before sorting and grouping? Also, there is no GIF image in the question showing the checklist inside a dropdown.

Comment: @bryan Monerrosa, Thank you for asking and looking into my post. I have added an image showing how the data is stored initially before sorting and grouping. And Added GIF image kind of checklist inside a dropdown. :)

Comment: Also added a table showing how the data is stored initially in Log Sheet for your reference. I can also share the sample sheet, but I am worried that I I've received the warning message reg. closure of the question if I post the sample sheet sharing. by the master forum :)